# type=1400 audit: avc: denied { read write }

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, android-kernel

> `type=1400 audit(506975.539:15): avc: denied { read write } for pid=5920 comm="print" name="prn0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1600 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0`

Getting this issue in Android kernel.

How to fix this issue. Is there anyone who can help.

Comment: Looks like SELinux issue. Either put your SELinux in permissive mode (e.g. via kernel cmdline), or create corresponding SELinux rule. Take a look [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate) for details.

Comment: yeah to edit SELinux rules tried these methods ----- allow untrusted_app device:chr_file { read write }; allow untrusted_app prn0:chr_file { read write }; added these lines in untruste app.te file but none of these worked

Comment: Similar with Docker: [audit:. type=1400 audit: apparmor=“DENIED” operation=“ptrace” profile=“docker-default”](https://askubuntu.com/q/1038298/78223).

Comment: Hey, have you find any solution about this? To do that do you have to root the android device?

Comment: I get this same issue, have you fixed it?